# ngrx effect: expect both actions to finish

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

How can I create a ngrx effect which triggers ONLY if both actions complete and return value?

Example: actionASuccess + actionBSuccess -> effect

I tried this solution: [How to wait for 2 Actions in @ngrx/effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44593306/how-to-wait-for-2-actions-in-ngrx-effects) with combineLatest or ofType(...waitFor) but both do not work as expected.

Here is my code. The content of the switchMap gets called twice but should be called only once:

```
navigateEmployeeNotificationsTypeSuccess$ = createEffect(() =>
combineLatest([
  this.actions$.pipe(ofType(RouterActions.navigateSuccess)),
  this.actions$.pipe(ofType(RouterActions.navigateEmployeeNotificationsTypeSuccess)),
]).pipe(
  filter(
    ([action1, action2]) =>
      RouterEffects.notNull(action1.success) && RouterEffects.notNull(action2.tab) && RouterEffects.notNull(action2.notificationsType),
  ),
  switchMap(([{ success }, { tab, notificationsType }]) => {
    if (success) {
      // have to set all sections active = false before changing state of the current
      const data = cloneDeep(tab.data);
      data.notificationTypes = data.notificationTypes.map((notificationType: NotificationType) => {
        const active = isEqual(notificationType, notificationsType);
        return {
          ...notificationType,
          active,
        };
      });

      return [
        TabsActions.setTabData({ tab, data }),
        TabsActions.saveCurrentRoute({ url: this.router.url }),
        TabsActions.replaceLastBreadcrumb({ breadcrumb: notificationsType.managerName }),
      ];
    }

    return EMPTY;
  }),
  catchError((error) => of(requestError({ error }))),
),
```

);

Comment: Try changing the `combineLatest` to a `forkJoin`.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that i assume is happening is that `RouterActions.navigateSuccess` is being called multiple times, so the `combineLatest` will emit value multiple times (given also that `RouterActions.navigateEmployeeNotificationsTypeSuccess` has emitted single value).

The approach that I will recommend to you is the chain both of those actions with a `switchMap` operator, otherwise you will end in funny situation whenver you navigate to `navigateEmployeeNotificationsTypeSuccess` => navigate out => navigate again to `navigateEmployeeNotificationsTypeSuccess` , in this case you will execute the logic inside the effect even more times.

So my `switchMap` based approach will look something like the following (assuming that `RouterActions.navigateSuccess` is being dispatched prior to `RouterActions.navigateEmployeeNotificationsTypeSuccess`)

```js
navigateEmployeeNotificationsTypeSuccess$ = createEffect(() =>
combineLatest([
  this.actions$.pipe(ofType(RouterActions.navigateSuccess)),
  this.actions$.pipe(ofType(RouterActions.navigateEmployeeNotificationsTypeSuccess)),
])
...

To be

navigateEmployeeNotificationsTypeSuccess$ = createEffect(() =>
this.actions$.pipe(ofType(RouterActions.navigateSuccess)).pipe(
    switchmap(() => this.actions$.pipe(ofType(RouterActions.navigateEmployeeNotificationsTypeSuccess)))
...
```